# Create directory structure in azure file share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I am trying to create a folder structure in azure file share. I am doing this from a web app. My code looks like this:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);

CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

//Get a reference for the share
CloudFileShare cloudFileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference(VideosDirectoryName);  

// Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
CloudFileDirectory rootDir = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();

// Try to get a reference for the new folder
CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(storagePath);

//create the directory structure
sampleDir.CreateAsync();
```

> storagePath looks like: 2017\03\13\d68dd25587624b8691a05834466cfc11

When I run this code nothing happens. No exception is thrown but no folder is created. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Meanwhile, I found [this answer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/351) which says that I need to create level by level. I will try that.

Comment: So what happens when you do build it level-by-level?

Comment: If I run the commands one after the other only the first directory gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use fiddler to capture request while you create multi-level directory structure via Azure storage SDK, you will find it sends a request like this.

> PUT https://{storageaccount}.file.core.windows.net/{sharename}/2017%5C03%5C13%5C0945682c-2214-49a5-93ba-10ac105532ea?restype=directory

and you will find status is **404**.

[image]

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/create-directory), we could find that the parent directory must already exist within the share before mydirectory can be created.

Comment: If I create a directory at one time, how can I wait between commands? Because I want to create the entire structure in one method.

Comment: You could try to wait for each creating directory operation to finish  ``sampleDir.CreateAsync().Wait();``.